# Retrofit example with a json response that include Json array and Json object, both?

Tags: android, retrofit

I need an example for my android sample retrofit app that handles a single json response that includes both json array and json object data.

Any help would mean a lot to me :)

Here is the json response. I've used it from this link

```
{
availability: "0",
results: [
{

key1: 5,
key2: 16,
key3: "My key"
}

],
count: 15,
activitycount: "0"
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of response? What type of webcall do you want do (sync or async)? In any case you should create a model that rapresent your response.

Comment: I have added the response to my post. I do understand the model thing. I'm done with it. Also getting the data successfully in onSuccess method of retrofit. Im getting the availability, count and activity count values. however the json array returns 0 or null values. I mean the inner "results" part

Comment: Sorry mate ! My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `List` in your retrofit response object when you have to use JSON arrays.

So your model would look like this

```
public class ResponseObject {
    public String availability;
    public int count;
    public String activitycount;
    public List<Results> results;

    public class Results {
         public int key1;
         public int key2;
         public String key3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes should be right. I use ArrayList in my app but I think that List works fine too @Abhilash

Comment: @iwen Yes iwen. It works fine now :) ! Thank you all ! God bless Stackverflow